# JSON parse multidimensional array volley

Tags: java, json, multidimensional-array

I stumbled upon a problem while trying to parse a JSON in my android app. In the screenshot below I provided the structure of the JSON. I can't get further than getting the "geometry" JSONObject. Eventually I need an array containing LatLng's for each "feature".

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

This is my code.

```
 //gets the area's out of the JSON
    JsonObjectRequest LosLoopJson = new JsonObjectRequest(losloopURL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONArray features = response.getJSONArray("features");

                for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Area = features.getJSONObject(i);

                    for (int x = 0; x < features.length(); x++) {
                        JSONObject geometry = Area.getJSONObject("geometry");
                        Double[][][] coordinates = geometry.get("coordinates");


                    }

                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(objectrequest);
```

And here is my JSON structure:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post code, not images. Also tip: do everything in english instead of dutch, variable names, comments, etc

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than screenshots. That way, other users can copy your code and try for themselves. As for your problem; you can make `coordinates` of type `JSONArray` and to loop over your LatLongs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordinate is a json array and each element in it, also contains a json array. So you've to iterate over the coordinate object.

```
JSONArray coordinates = geometry.get("coordinates");
for(int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++)
    JSONArray coord   = coordinates.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("features");
        for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (jsonObject1.has("geomerty")){
                JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("geomerty");
                for (int j = 0; j <= jsonArray1.length(); j++){
                    if (jsonObject1.has("coordinates")){
                        JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                        for (int k = 0; k <= jsonArray2.length();k++){
                            JSONArray jsonArray3 = jsonArray2.getJSONArray(k);
                            for (int l =0; l <= jsonArray3.length(); l++){
                                Log.d("ABC", String.valueOf(jsonArray3.getDouble(l)));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I got it working using this code:

```
 //gets the area's out of the JSON
    JsonObjectRequest LosLoopJson = new JsonObjectRequest(losloopURL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONArray features = response.getJSONArray("features");

                for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Area = features.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject geometry = Area.getJSONObject("geometry");
                    JSONArray coordinates = geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");
                    JSONArray AreaCoordinates = coordinates.getJSONArray(0);

                    //Log.d("Debug", "Feature: " + String.valueOf(i + 1));

                        for (int y = 0; y < AreaCoordinates.length(); y++) {
                            //Log.d("Debug", "Coordinate: " + String.valueOf(y + 1));

                            JSONArray DoubleCoordinate = AreaCoordinates.getJSONArray(y);
                            Double latitude = DoubleCoordinate.getDouble(1);
                            Double longitude = DoubleCoordinate.getDouble(0);
                            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                            LosLoopGebied.add(coordinate);
                        }

                        losloopgebieden.add(LosLoopGebied);
                        LosLoopGebied.clear();

                }


            //PlaatsLosLoopGebieden();
                //Log.d("Debug", "Heeft de losloopgebieden opgehaalt uit JSON");
                //Log.d("Debug", "Er zijn " + String.valueOf(LosLoopGebied.size()) + " coordinaten opgehaalt");
                Log.d("Debug", "Er zijn " + String.valueOf(losloopgebieden.size()) + " opgehaalt uit JSON");


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(LosLoopJson);
```